# Building a menu retrieving data using model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I'm trying to build a menu using model relationship. Menu items are Categories and Products. I'd like to have a list of Categories with every single line of Category listing their own products. I'm afraid I'm missing the whole logic of this.

My first model:

```
class Categoria extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'categorie';

    public function prodotti()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Prodotto','categoria_id');
    }
}
```

My second model:

```
class Prodotto extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'prodotti';

        public function categoria()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Categoria', 'categoria_id');
        }

}
```

'categorie' table fields are:

```
('id', 'nome', 'descrizione'...)
```

'prodotti' table fields are:

```
('id', 'categoria_id', 'codice'...)
```

My controller is:

```
class SiteController extends BaseController {


    public function menuHome()
    {
        $categorie = Categoria::where('attivo', '=', '1')->orderBy('nome','asc')->get();

        $prodotti = Categoria::find(1)->prodotti()->get();

        return View::make('index')
        ->with('categorie',$categorie)
        ->with('prodotti',$prodotti);
    }
}
```

Migrations are:

1)

```
class CreateCategorie extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorie', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nome', 255);
            $table->text('descrizione')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('attivo')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categorie');
    }

}
```

2)

```
class CreateProdotti extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prodotti', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('categoria_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorie');
            $table->string('codice', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('produttore', 255);
            $table->string('modello', 255);
            $table->text('descrizione')->nullable();
            $table->string('tipo', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('lungmax', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('peso', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('certificazioni', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('prove', 255)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('venduto')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('attivo')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('prodotti');
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to build the whole from inside this view:

```
<!-- TEST -->
 <div class="well">
  @foreach($categorie as $categoria)
  <ul>
    <li>{{ $categoria->nome }}</li>
      <ul>
       @foreach($prodotti as $prodotto)
        <li>{{ $prodotto->codice }}</li>
       @endforeach
      </ul>
    </ul>
  @endforeach
 </div>
<!-- /TEST -->
```

And it obviously doesn't work.

I changed the view this way and it works perfectly:

```
<div class="well">
  @foreach($categorie as $categoria)
    <ul>
      <li>{{ $categoria->nome }}</li>
      <ul>
      @foreach(Prodotto::where('categoria_id', '=', $categoria->id)->get() as $prodotto)
        <li><a href="#">{{ $prodotto->codice }}</a></li>
      @endforeach
      </ul>
    </ul>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

How can I translate this in an elegant "Eloquent way"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
@foreach($prodotti as $prodotto)
```

With :

```
@foreach($categorie->prodotti as $prodotto)
```

and let me know if it works.

Also since you are using Eloquent relationships you only need

```
return View::make('index')
    ->with('categorie',$categorie);
```

without touching the Prodotti model :

```
 public function menuHome()
{
    $categorie = Categoria::where('attivo', '=', '1')->orderBy('nome','asc')->get();

    return View::make('index')
    ->with('categorie',$categorie);

}
```

**EDIT :** try also changing to this one :

```
       public function prodotti()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Prodotto', 'categoria_id', 'id');
}

 public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Categoria', 'categoria_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Replacing with '@foreach($categorie->prodotti as $prodotto)' error is: _Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$prodotti (View: /var/www_

Comment: @Asmodai-Didn't work either but I added an edit, see please if it could help, thx a lot

Comment: That was the last edit i was going to suggest you, because it is working out of the eloquent relationships. It seems the problem is somewhere in the foreign-local keys assignment in the relationships.Try once my last edit and lets see if it will make a difference.

Comment: Nothing changed. Added Migration for further info, maybe might help. Thanx.